# how can I add some hours in PHP/Carbon?

Tags: php, date, datetime-format, php-carbon

I am using Laravel and have this code:

```
$date = now()->locale('es_ES');

$start_date = $date->isoFormat('D [de] MMMM [de] YYYY')
$start_time = $date->isoFormat('HH[H]hh')
$end_date =  $date->addHours(3)->isoFormat('D [de] MMMM [de] YYYY')
$end_time =  $date->addHours(3)->isoFormat('HH[H]hh')
```

this is the output

start_date : 24 de abril de 2023
start_time : 21H09
end_date : 25 de abril de 2023
end_time: 03H03

I would like the end date and time to be something like this:

end_date: 25 de abril de 2023
end_time: 00H09

it looks like it is adding more then 3 hours, and also the minutes is different, what is happening? thanks

Comment: you are working with the same date. you call `addHours(3)` 2 times on the initial `$date` - so, it adds 6 hours instead of 3. either call `->copy()` like `->copy()->addHours()` or just call it 1 time.

Comment: it works, but only for the hours, the minutes remain with the same error

Comment: Now it works, the minutes must be mm, not hh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want minute, you need `mm` instead of `hh`, then you should copy the date and add hours only once:

```php
$date = now()->locale('es_ES');

$start_date = $date->isoFormat('D [de] MMMM [de] YYYY');
$start_time = $date->isoFormat('HH[H]mm');

$end = $date->copy()->addHours(3);

$end_date =  $end->isoFormat('D [de] MMMM [de] YYYY');
$end_time =  $end ->isoFormat('HH[H]mm');
```

(note that `now()` is creating a mutable `Carbon` object, switch to `CarbonImmutable` to have immutable instead is also an option)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
    $start = now()->locale('es_ES');
    $end = $start->copy()->addHours(3);
    
    $start_date = $start->isoFormat('D [de] MMMM [de] YYYY');
    $start_time = $start->isoFormat('HH[H]hh');
    $end_date = $end->isoFormat('D [de] MMMM [de] YYYY');
    $end_time = $end->isoFormat('HH[H]hh');
```